# London TimeZone off by one hour - StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, timestamps, voting-limits

The SO limits you to:

- 40 vote casts per day
- 20 Suggested Edits
- 40 close vote reviews
  ..etc

**To be clear**

If I exceed any of the above limits, like now and try to vote again: "Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in x time.".

Now until 12 PM, this time will be the difference between "now" and 12 PM. If I try to perform any of the aforementioned actions at 00:01AM, I ALWAYS get "Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 1 hour".

And the fact stands. The limitations are refreshed at 01:00AM London Time every day.

**Display bug**

At 23:01PM: Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 1 hour.

At 00:01AM: Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 1 hour.

Comment: We operate on UTC, not local timezones.

Comment: Though this may very well be a genuine bug, where we are not using UTC properly everywhere. To be investigated.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow, and the rest of the Stack Exchange network of sites uses UTC days, not local times (such as GMT with / without DST).

Will have to look at the reset you mentioned - this may indeed be a bug.

---

Update:

The time resolution on the message is why this is happening. During conversion to a relative time string, if the delta is over an hour but less then two hours, you will see "in 1 hour".

If it is less then an hour, you will see the message in minutes.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up!

Comment: But why the display variation? Why do I get the correct time if it's before twelve and then a magic reset after?

Comment: @alex23 -Where exactly do you see explicit times?

Comment: Vote limitations: 
Before 00:00AM I get: "Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in X hours". X is the correct difference between 12 and the current London time.( so now I get "Vote again in two hours")

Comment: After 00:00 AM I get a magic reset, saying "Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 1 hour".

Comment: @alex23 - So, at 23:01 you would get "Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 1 hour" and then at 00:01 again "Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 1 hour"?

Comment: Exactly, not sure where the bug comes from. I can do screenshots if it's of any help.

Comment: @alex23 - No, no need for those. May very well be a bug then - something using local time instead of UTC.

Comment: @Oded Is that not simply the precision of the message? I.e. 1h59 to go results in "1 hour"?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - regardless. Getting a "... in 1 hour" message for two hours in a row can't be right.

Comment: @Bart - Possibly. Need to check what this is. It may be our "smart" relative time conversion :)

Comment: @Oded: The time functions do seem off. There's 2 hours left until UTC midnight and I'm seeing *"Thank you for reviewing 40 Close Votes today; come back in 1 hour to continue reviewing."*